# How to prevent Mailgun emails from going into junk folder?

Tags: outlook, mailgun, spam

Emails sent to Microsoft Outlook email via Mailgun go into junk folder. Mailgun embeds transparent 1x1 image in the body of email to collect statistics. I think that is the reason why Outlook marks those emails as spam. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the sender's address from Mailgun to your white list in outlook, so that any messages sent from that address will not go to Junk Email.
Click "junk" under "Home" and select "junk E-mail options" in the drop-down list".
The box below will pop up. Click "safe senders" and click "Add" to Add the sender address of the email you sent with the Mailgun.
Any messages sent from this address will not enter spam.

[image: Operating picture]